# Can someone suggest me a NoSQL database which is good for frequent updates?

Tags: database, nosql, distributed, cassandra

I have heard that NoSQL databases like Cassandra, Couchbase etc are not good for frequent updates of data. They behave well when the data inserted doesn't change often. My use case is to save/update the data coming from the stream which will involve a lot of inserts and updates. Can someone suggest me a NoSQL which performs even when the application is written (save/update) intensive

Comment: [AWS DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) is worth a try,

Comment: Cassandra I could see why frequent updates could be an issue, but Couchbase is a whole different model, and can definitely support frequent updates well.